# temporal overlap in R - with overlap package. What to do with kmax, n.grid, adjust, cores, and 95CI type for the kernel activity estimates

Tags: android-activity, kernel, overlap, temporal

I am currently analysing the spatial en temporal overlap between apex predator leopard (n25) and mesocarnivores genet (n239) and civet (n125). For the temporal overlap I am using the "overlap" package in R. Because of the small sample size of leopards, I am using Dhat1, smooth=true and either basic0 or norm0. These parameters I could figure out from the documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/overlap/overlap.pdf). However, it is very unclear to me what I have to do with the next parameters:

I do not exactly understand what I have to do with the following parameters; do I need to use them? If so, what value do I need to use and how this it affect the outcome?

- **kmax**    (maximum value of k for optimal bandwidth estimation)
- **Adjust**   (bandwidth adjustment; either a single value used for all 3 overlap estimates, or a    vector of 3 different values. If adjust=NA in bootstrap, adjust will be set to 0.8 for type="Dhat1", 1 for type="Dhat4" and 4 for type="Dhat5")
- **N.grid**  (number of points at which to estimate density for comparison between species; smaller values give lower precision but run faster in bootstraps)
- **Cores**    (the number of cores to use for parallel processing. If NA, all but one of the available cores will used. Parallel processing may take longer than serial processing if the bootstrap runs quickly.

I also had a question regarding the type of confidence interval. “basic” and “norm” are used when there is a bias in the data (which is the case). However, “basic0” or “norm0” should be used with a sample size <50 (which is also the case). I assume, I should continue with either “basic0” or “norm0”? Which of the two is better? For example, what would be the benefit of using tail cut-offs?

It also occurred to me that following the documentation, I did not use all the functions. Is it correct that I should not use these? Or what are they used for? And why should(n’t) I use them?

- **densityFit()** Fits von Mises kernel density to time-of-day data.
- **densityFit(x, grid, bw)**
- **getBandWidth()** Optimal bandwidth calculation.
- **overlapTrue()** Calculates the true coefficient of overlapping between two distributions.

What I already did:
I followed the example from the documentation. This example uses none of the parameters. It does give me an output. However, I still want to understand why or why not I shouuld use those parameters.